# SharePoint Site automatically becomes unavailable daily

Tags: 2010, uls, internal-server-error

We have several SharePoint Intranet and Internet sites running in a multi-farm environment. These several sites are monitored by a real-time application monitoring tool. One of the SharePoint 2010 Internet site keep going down daily for 5 minutes and automatically its up after 5 minutes. We receive notification alert from the monitoring tool whenever this site goes down. The alert received is something like -

> The resource http://www.mySharePointSite.com is not available. Internal Server Error
>
> **Reason:** Resource Down

I explored Event Viewer logs, ULS log files, SQL Server logs but found nothing related to resouce/site unavailability or any critical message that indicates site unavailability.

What could be the possible reason for site automatically becoming unavailable and what is the best approach to reach to the root cause?

Comment: what about Windows Log and IIS Logs? Do u have some particolar web parts in the site? or custom timre job in the web application?

Answer (score 0):

If it happens every 29th hour then I'd suspect IIS recycling.

If not then I'd look at custom code which:

1. might access some other ressource which is unavailable at that point in time.
2. has a cache expiration of something which takes 5 minutes to read

Or it might be due to backup or timer job taking all the server resources.